# Macro method has 2 returns?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I've just moved over from Java to C++ and I've never used macros before and I'm confused how some methods seem to return two variables, such as

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
```

or even stranger combinations like

```
JNIEXPORT jdoubleArray JNICALL Java_algorithms_Shuffle0_getPriorities (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jint).
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? Sorry if this seems like extreme ignorance, but as I say I've never used macros before and The Complete Reference to C++ chapter on the preprocessor doesn't make these arrangements any clearer.

Comment: Macros don't really "return" anything.  They are just textual substitutions.  So `#define FOO 42` and `bar(FOO)` becomes `bar(42)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to expand each macro to fully understand it. Run your code through the pre-processor to see how it expands, or use your helpful IDE tools to show you.

When you do so you will see the following:

- `LRESULT` is the result type. It's an integer of some description.
- `CALLBACK` defines the calling convention which would be `__stdcall`.

And as for the other one:

- `JNIEXPORT` probably expands to `declspec(dllexport)`. This specifies that the function is to be exported from the library.
- `jdoubleArray` is the return value.
- `JNICALL` will be the calling convention.

You can think of these extra tokens as being decorators to the function. They do not change the signature of the function at a conceptual level. Probably the closest analogous concept in Java would be attributes.

Comment: Thanks, it's the calling convention part I missed. It makes sense now.